# R - Need to extract two dataset but getting error "Error in fix.by(by.y, y)"

Tags: r

I am trying to merge two datasets

1. `se_lif_1` with columns `SE_NO` and `TOT_CV_LIF`
2. `ext_merchant_account` with the 76 columns that include:

   "SE_NO","SEIMS_INDUS_DS_CD","CUR_MER_STA_CD","CLNT_MAN_CHAN_CD","MER_SETUP_DT"

By using below code:

```
se_lif_2 <- merge(se_lif_1,
     ext_merchant_account[(ext_merchant_account$CUR_MER_STA_CD %in%
     c("A","R")) & (ext_merchant_account$CLNT_MAN_CHAN_CD %in% 
     c("I","X", " ")) & (ext_merchant_account$MER_SETUP_DT < 
     S_date),"SEIMS_INDUS_DS_CD"],by = "SE_NO" )
```

But was getting below error:

```
"Error in fix.by(by.y, y) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column"
```

Also `S_date` is a object with class "Date" containing a single record which I am using in one of the logical condition to subset the data from `ext_merchant_account` data frame.

I also checked the class of the variable in "by", which is same for both the dataset (i.e an integer).

I also tried using `by.x` & `by.y` but was getting the same error again.Could any one point out the error that I am doing in this code.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Cheers,

Amit

Comment: Please show a reproducible example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Do you have `SE_NO` column in the output of `ext_merchant_account[(ext_merchant_account$CUR_MER_STA_CD %in%
     c("A","R")) & (ext_merchant_account$CLNT_MAN_CHAN_CD %in% 
     c("I","X", " ")) & (ext_merchant_account$MER_SETUP_DT < 
     S_date),"SEIMS_INDUS_DS_CD"]`.  By just looking at the code, it seems that you have only `"SEIMS_INDUS_DS_CD"` column.

Comment: I think you can use `by.x='SE_NO', by.y='SEIMS_INDUS_DS_CD)` if both columns represents the same 'SE_NO'

Comment: yes, but was getting the same error even after selecting all the columns

Comment: It was just a guess.  Without an example data or str() of both datasets, it is hard to say what might be wrong in your code

Comment: @akrun : Thanks a lot .......there was some syntax error before when I tried to select all columns from the dataset "ext_merchant_account" ....now able to merge the dataset properly by using below code:

merge(se_lif_1,ext_merchant_account[(ext_merchant_account$CUR_MER_STA_CD %in% c("A","R")) & (ext_merchant_account$CLNT_MAN_CHAN_CD %in% c("I","X"," ")) & (ext_merchant_account$MER_SETUP_DT < S_date),c("SE_NO","SEIMS_INDUS_DS_CD")], by = c('SE_NO'))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you failed to select `SE_MO` in your code. To use `merge` both data frames need to share a common variable. Most likely, one data frame is missing `SE_MO`.

The merge code should look like:

```
newDF=merge(df1,df2,by=SE_MO)
```

To rename a variable you may want to use:

```
names(df1)[1]=c("SE_MO") #'1' refers to location of column
```

Comment: But was getting the same error even when selecting all the columns from the dataset "ext_merchant_account" , will be sharing table structure and sample data soon.